# How to create Regular Expressions for Israel landlines and mobile phone validation specific phone codes?

Tags: regex, validation, phone-number

**Task is:**

Create Regular Expressions for Israel landlines and mobile phone validation specific phone codes

Specific phone codes is :

```
02,03,04,08,09,050,051,052,053,054,055,056,058,059,072,074,076,077,078,079
```

Validate entered phone does not start with `"0"` or `"1"`.

Phone number length always `7` for mobile and landline phone numbers.

Already create reg exp for this task:

```
/^(02|03|04|06|08|09|072|074|076|077|078|079|050|051|052|053|054|055|056|058|059)((?:(?![1,0]{1}))\d{7})$/
```

You can visit the link to check :

https://regex101.com/r/GRTns5/1/

How to optimize or another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify a bit with:

```
^0(?:[234689]|5[0-689]|7[246789])(?![01])(\d{7})$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GRTns5/2)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can optimize here is the first group with phone codes:

```
    ^(0(?:5[0-689]|7[246-9]|[2-4689]))((?:(?![1,0]{1}))\d{7})$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3j2lbl/2)